# Recommended Microsoft 365/SharePoint REST API/Graph API JS library - for custom solution not in SharePoint context

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, microsoft-graph, office-dev-pnp

I'm after a reliable REST API JS library i can use to build a custom solution using SharePoint Online backend rest services.
This app would be hosted outside the SharePoint context
I know of [this](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/getting-started/)

the **PnP JS library** but are there other recommenced libraries that is avaialabe?

Any resources would be appreciated and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This one is an old one, SPServices: https://sympmarc.github.io/SPServices/

It's built mostly on the old client side apis but can still be used with Office365 (and all the way back to SharePoint 2007). I haven't used it in years and it doesn't include Graph, but if you're looking to avoid SP Context and Azure App registration then it might work work for you.

Still I'd recommend the PnP lib as it's more current, especially if you plan to support modern pages and so on as SPServices is only for classic SharePoint.